# How CVs in discipline with numerous co-authors are examined?

Tags: publications, research-process, cv, faculty-application

In some disciplines such as theoretical physics, it is common to have tens (or even) hundreds of co-authors, probably because of the essential role of many people to run highly advanced facility.

How is the list of publications in these disciplines judged? For a faculty appointment, how does the search committee realize the scientific contribution of the applicant?

Comment: Theoretical physics? Did you mean experimental physics? Usually the mean density of authors/paper in theoretical fields are low.